# TeamViewer wants a password for the Options dialog

Tags: security, passwords, teamviewer

I can login to my TeamViewer account but when I try to add a computer to the "Computers & Contacts" dialog I get a login prompt. This doesn't accept my account password. What other password is there?

[image: Login prompt]

Answer (score 9):

You can protect the options with a password. I don't know why that would pop up when you try to add a computer though.

One way to get rid of that password is to uninstall TeamViewer and activate the checkbox to remove all settings and then reinstall it again. Another way would be to remove the registry key for the password (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version9 OptionsPasswordAES) and restart the TeamViewer service.

Comment: Depending on the version the key can also be in other subfolders of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer`. It seems also that settings of earlier versions propagate on later versions (I had a password under `Version8` which affected the behaviour of my version 10.

Comment: After removing 'OptionsPasswordAES' , worked well for me

Answer (score -1):

It is called `two factor authentication`.

There are two possible ways to deactivate two factor authentication.

Deactivate two factor authentication in your user profile settings:

```
Login with your TeamViewer account at login.teamviewer.com
Click on your profile name an select Edit profile
Click the Deactivate link under General | Two factor authentication
Enter the security code displayed by your authenticator app
Click the Deactivate button
```

There is also way to remove using a recovery code (see link below)

[Source for all the above](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/402-How-do-I-activate-deactivate-two-factor-authentication-for-my-TeamViewer-account.aspx)

Comment: I tried that but Two factor authentication has "Activate" next to it.

Comment: Try to activate it, then deactive it @parsley72? Do you have different versions installed?

Comment: This is not related in any way to 2-factor authentication - totally different issue.

Answer (score -2):

if you have the password.....you can disable it extras > options > advanced
advanced, show advanced options, scroll all the way to the bottom and delete the password and confirming password from "Protect options with password"

**but that doesnt help you if you dont know the password already,** it just disables that requirement for extra authentication